# Insert Date into sql table with Date column

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Hello and thanks for reading.

I'm trying to insert the current date into my table, but I can't figure out how to write it correctly.

Here is my C# code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

string Comment = UserWriteComment.Text;
string ID = DetailedID.Text;
string Name = DetailedName.Text;
string UniqueID = lblID.Text;


string query = "INSERT INTO Comment(TicketID, Name, Comments, UserID, Date)" + "Values('" + ID + "', '" + Name + "', '" + Comment + "', '" + UniqueID + "', '" + Date + "')";
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    UserWriteComment.Text = "";
}
```

In the Query, There is a value called Date. This is here I like the Function to pass the current date into my Table.

I hope you can help me because I didnt managed to find the answer anywere.

Thanks:)

Comment: What is the problem? did you get any error or unexpected result?

Comment: Yes I got an error but that is most likely because I cant write the string thats needed correctly.

Comment: Just use a GetDate() without the quotes around it.

Comment: If I could get a bit of code, I would be so happy.

Comment: What is the text of the error message?

Comment: string query = "INSERT INTO Comment(TicketID, Name, Comments, UserID, Date)" + "Values('" + ID + "', '" + Name + "', '" + Comment + "', '" + UniqueID + "', GetDate()";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or (in the database via sql) [`GetDate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx). But more important, use sql-parameters to prevent [sql-injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?ppud=4) and conversion/localization issues:

```
string insertSql = @"INSERT INTO Comment(TicketID, Name, Comments, UserID, Date)
                     Values(@ID, @Name, @Comment, @UniqueID, @Date)";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("...."))
using (var com = new SqlCommand(insertSql, conn))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", Comment);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqueID", UniqueID);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
    conn.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The `using`-statement ensures that unmanaged resources like the connection will be disposed/closed even in case of an error.

Answer (score 5):

Use `DateTime.Now` instead of `Date`. i.e. update the `INSERT` line to the following.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Comment(TicketID, Name, Comments, UserID, Date)" 
              + "Values('" + ID + "', '" + Name + "', '" + Comment + "', '" 
              + UniqueID + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "')";
```

P.S: You really should be using Parameterize statements to avoid a Bobby Tables situation.

[image]

To fix this, implement it as shown by @Tim in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21740969/325521):

Comment: This also a valid option,

Comment: +1 for the comical approach to recommending SqlParameter usage :)

Comment: Awesome Thanks, didnt thought it was that "easy" as just using datatime.now in the Values parameter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Date, try using the following

```
DateTime.Now
```

Another function that can help you is

```
 GETDATE()
```

Comment: you could also consider using getdate() as the default field value in your table, unless you'll have timezone problems between appserver and database server.

Answer (score 0):

Date inserts for SQL Server is best used via :

```
GetDate()
```

or

```
Convert(Varchar, GetDate(), 101)
```

Note: converting the `GetDate()` value to `varchar` type 101 shortens the value to just the `date w/o time stamp`.